# Why Does Omniauth-twitter Work Only When I Uncheck "Sign In With Twitter"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

This post is about Ruby on Rails development with social media log in functionality implemented by Omniauth.

## This seems a little counterintuitive, but why Omniauth (Omniauth-Twitter) doesn't work if I check the "Sign in with twitter" in the developer setting?

What I did was: I went to go to Twitter Developer -> My Applications (top right corner) -> My App -> Settings -> uncheck "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter"

On the other hand, if I disable "sign in with Twitter", the sign in with Twitter function works as expected :-Q!!!

Since I'm a newbie and Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post images, here's a link to my blog with a screenshot on Wordpress.

http://sexyadventure.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/twitter-sign-in-problem-solved-in-a-rather-odd-n-simple-way/

And the code I was experimenting was from here: https://github.com/jamiew/omniauth-rails-app
All I did was typing in my own Twitter api key and secret without changing any code.